# Why does $A \times B \cap \operatorname{diag} X^2 = \emptyset$ imply $A \cap B = \emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Why does  $(A \times B) \cap \operatorname{diag}X^2 = \emptyset$ imply $A \cap B = \emptyset$ ?
where $A \times B \subset X \times X$ and $\operatorname{diag}X^2 =\{(x,x) \mid x \in X\}$ and $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a topological space.

Comment: Parentheses, please.

Comment: To expand on @Git Gud’s comment, it’s clearer if you write $$(A\times B)\cap\operatorname{diag}X^2\;.$$

Comment: I cannot see any topological notions being used in this question, so why is it tagged general-topology?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x \in A \cap B$, then clearly $(x,x) \in A \times B$ and $(x,x) \in \operatorname{diag} X^2$, so $(A \times B) \cap \operatorname{diag} X^2 \neq \emptyset$.

In addition, if $(a,b) \in (A \times B) \cap \operatorname{diag} X^2$, then we must have $a=b$, hence $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, so in fact it is an equivalence.

Comment: I changed \text{diag}X^2 to \operatorname{diag}X^2.  The latter causes suitable spacing to appear before and after "diag".

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks! My Latex is primitive.